# Ajuda para inserir dados na tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no *MySQL* com o nome `usuários` com os seguintes itens: `convite`,`quantidade_de_convites`. Quero que ao adicionar um convite, atualizar a quantidade como faço isso?.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer atualizar a tabela de usuários após inserir um registro na tabela convite,  você pode utilizar uma TRIGGER. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_convite AFTER INSERT ON convite
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE usuarios SET quantidade_de_convites = quantidade_de_convites + 1 WHERE USUARIO_ID = NEW.USUARIO_iD;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

No caso deste exemplo, a tabela de usuário receberia um campo chamado usuario_id, ele seria a chave para atualizar a tabela de usuários

Aqui tem um tutorial explicando como funcionam triggers

https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-basico-triggers/37462

Comment: preciso fazer algo antes de criar a trigger? aqui ta dando erro de tabela